# How can I determine the process for what is listening on the network in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, administrator, netstat

When I use netstat -tup, it only shows the processes for some. There are other ports that just have a - for PID, so how would I find out what process is listening on these ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display this list, for lines that have no process name, can you check the state of the tcp socket?

If it is a closing socket, the process may have disconnected and the TCP Stack might be just cleaning up the connection.

Secondly, are you running the `netstat` command with `root` rights?
If you do not have rights to the process, its name will not be listed.
Actually, if that happens, most netstat versions will show a warning about this before listing the output.

Comment: Running it with root rights shows everything. Thanks

Why though can I see the processes with ps aux, but not with netstat?

Comment: @Jack A normal user can see all listening ports and all running processes - but cannot see which process is using which ports. (`ps` does not need this information.)

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is use lsof.

Lets say you wanted to know all process that are using port 80, you could type:

```
lsof -i :80
```

And get a list of processes that are listening/using port 80. As well as program name and user.

Comment: Ahh, thankyou. I didn't know I could use lsof for that.